# Firebase updates UI after completion using Android

Tags: android, firebase, asynchronous, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am using Kotlin to create an Android App. The problem I am having is I’m trying to use a ViewModel to create an user in Firebase. After the user is created, something should be returned to the UI Fragment to let the fragment know to move forward to the next line of execution. The trouble I’m having is Firebase operations are done asynchronously, so there’s no way for me the front end to know the operation is done executing in the view model. **Is there a way to create a callback or fix this?**

Comment: If you are interested in a clean Firebase authentication with Google, you can check this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336). At the end of the article, you'll see how you can notify the user.

Comment: Hi Alex, I am trying to just do a basic Firebase Authentication right now. The only problem I have is creating a call back function with Kotlin in my View Model class.